# re pattern doesnt recognize comma value

Tags: regex, pandas, match, apply

I hope you can help me with this one.

I'm running an apply method on a pandas dataframe to identify if the value has a correct number format (since some of them have a comma value separating the thousands). Thing is that, as far as i can seen my regex pattern doesnt recognize the comma value. Here's my code:

```
def afloat(x):
    x=str(x)
    pattern=re.compile(r"\d+,\d\d\d")
    return pattern.match(x)

data=["1,000","999","2,580"]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=["data"])

df["status"]=df.apply(lambda x: afloat(df["data"]),axis=1)
```

what I get is the following, even though there are comma values that, as far as i can tell, they do match with the pattern i'm defining:

```
    data    status
0   1,000   None
1   999 None
2   2,580   None
```

I just can't identify what i'm doing wrong. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked for me:

```py
import re

def afloat(x):
    x=str(x).replace(".",",")
    pattern=re.compile(r"\d+,\d\d\d")
    return pattern.match(x)

test = 100.123
print(afloat(test))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at what you pass to `.apply`, you will see where the trouble is: `.apply(lambda x: afloat(df["data"]),axis=1)` passes the *whole `df["data"]` column* and not its current row value.

Instead, you should use `.apply(lambda x: afloat(x["data"]),axis=1)` where `x` denotes the current row.

Now, the pattern you have is used with `re.match` and thus will only be searched for at the start of the string, but after it, there may be more text. To make sure you match the *entire* string with the pattern, add `$` at the end of the regex pattern.

However, since all you want to do is to check if a value matches some regex pattern and return a boolean column, you should consider using `Series.str.match`:

```py
>>> df['data'].str.match(r'\d+,\d{3}$')
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: data, dtype: bool
```

Here, `\d+,\d{3}$` will match a string that starts with 1+ digits, a comma, and then three digits up to the end of string.